# Clarification of jQuery DOM Traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, javascript-framework

I'm not sure I'm completely understanding the jQuery docs here when they say DOM traversal. Does it really mean traversing a copy of the DOM in the wrapper object? It seems to me the actual traversal is done when selecting elements, whereas using methods like .get() and .next() are really traversing a copy of the DOM. Am I right on this, or did I miss something?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: well, no .. i suppose. because when you apply `jquery` methods like `remove()` and `hide()` , they have actions

Comment: Do you mean no it's not traversing a copy?

Comment: well, it's just logic, mmm.. not sure. Since acting on copy doesn't produce the effects like `remove` and `hide`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery function returns an object. It has numeric properties whose values are **references** to DOM elements, not copies. So given the following:

```
<p id="p0">p0</p>
<p id="p1">p1</p>

<script>
var paragraphs = $('p');
</script>
```

paragraphs will be an object that has a '0' property whose value is a reference to the p element with id p0, and a '1' property that is a reference to the p element with id p1. You could reference the first p using:

```
paragraphs['0'];
```

jQuery helps with "traversing the DOM" in that you can use a selector (or multiple selectors) to "collect" elements as properties of an object, then iterate over the numeric properties of that object and do something with them. So to add a class to the p elements above, you can do:

```
paragraphs.each(function(i,el){$(el).addClass('newClass')})
```

The equivalent in plain javascript would be:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var i = paragraphs.length;
while (i--) {
    myLib.addClass(paragraphs[i], 'newClass');
}
```

Where myLib.addClass is a simple function to add a class to the className property. If the addClass function is a little smarter so it could accept an array (or array-like object) of element references, then the POJS version would be:

```
myLib.addClass(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), 'newClass');
```

So building equivalent *ad hoc* "DOM traversal" capability is not particularly difficult.